# Feedback on ValueError: I/O operation on closed file with python 3

Tags: python

I tried to read multiple PDF files in a folder with pdfminer3 to convert the content to text. Each input pdf should result in one output .txt
However I always end up with "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" on line *page_interpreter.process_page(page)*

When I use the while stament for a single pdf document with a static open pathI get a text file with the results.

Where is the problem with the for loop before that and why are the files closed prematurely?

```
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
import io
import os

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)

target_directory = "*insert_path_here*\\pdf\\Target\\"
save_directory = "*insert_path_here*\\pdf\\"


def readpdf():
    for fname in os.listdir(target_directory):
        with open(target_directory+fname, "rb") as fh:
            for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh,caching=True,check_extractable=True):
                page_interpreter.process_page(page)
            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            print(text)
#close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()
```

Comment: Would number of pages minus 1 help you to stop the loop before end of pdf file?

Comment: solution was to put the variables "resource_manager" (...) "save_dir" inside the *readpdf* function